# MPI fortran code compiled in linux and windows with cygwin

Tags: windows, fortran, mpi, openmpi

**The code and objectives**

I have a `fortran` `mpi` code called `elast3d_mpi.f` to be compiled in both **windows** and **linux** systems.

**The expected behavior**

The compilation in **linux** is performed as

```
mpif90 -o elast3d_mpi elast3d_mpi.f
```

Then the program can be executed in parallel with `mpirun` command

```
mpirun -n 2 elast3d_mpi
```

The terminal output allows to observe that 2 processors are running it, as is expected

```
 There are 2  processors running this job.
 Rank# 0 d1 = 1   d2 = 64
 Rank# 1 d1 = 65  d2 = 128
 ...
```

If the program is running without `mpirun` in **linux**, then it works without errors and without paralleling processing.

**The problem**

In order to compile it in windows, the `cygwin` environment is used. After installation of these packages

```
Package                  Version            Status
_autorebase              001007-1           OK
alternatives             1.3.30c-10         OK
base-cygwin              3.8-1              OK
base-files               4.3-2              OK
bash                     4.4.12-3           OK
binutils                 2.29-1             OK
bzip2                    1.0.8-1            OK
ca-certificates          2.32-1             OK
coreutils                8.26-2             OK
crypto-policies          20190218-1         OK
cygutils                 1.4.16-2           OK
cygwin                   3.0.7-1            OK
cygwin-debuginfo         3.0.7-1            OK
cygwin-devel             3.0.7-1            OK
dash                     0.5.9.1-1          OK
diffutils                3.5-2              OK
editrights               1.03-1             OK
file                     5.32-1             OK
findutils                4.6.0-1            OK
gawk                     5.0.1-1            OK
gcc-core                 7.4.0-1            OK
gcc-fortran              7.4.0-1            OK
getent                   2.18.90-4          OK
grep                     3.0-2              OK
groff                    1.22.4-1           OK
gzip                     1.8-1              OK
hostname                 3.13-1             OK
info                     6.7-1              OK
ipc-utils                1.0-2              OK
less                     530-1              OK
libargp                  20110921-3         OK
libatomic1               7.4.0-1            OK
libattr1                 2.4.48-2           OK
libblkid1                2.33.1-1           OK
libbz2_1                 1.0.8-1            OK
libcrypt0                2.1-1              OK
libfdisk1                2.33.1-1           OK
libffi6                  3.2.1-2            OK
libgc1                   8.0.4-1            OK
libgcc1                  7.4.0-1            OK
libgdbm4                 1.13-1             OK
libgfortran3             6.4.0-5            OK
libgfortran4             7.4.0-1            OK
libgmp10                 6.1.2-1            OK
libgomp1                 7.4.0-1            OK
libguile17               1.8.8-3            OK
libguile2.0_22           2.0.14-3           OK
libiconv                 1.14-3             OK
libiconv2                1.14-3             OK
libintl8                 0.19.8.1-2         OK
libisl15                 0.16.1-1           OK
libltdl7                 2.4.6-7            OK
liblzma5                 5.2.4-1            OK
libmpc3                  1.1.0-1            OK
libmpfr6                 4.0.2-1            OK
libncursesw10            6.1-1.20190727     OK
libopenmpi-devel         3.1.3-1            OK
libopenmpi12             1.10.7-1           OK
libopenmpi40             3.1.3-1            OK
libopenmpicxx1           1.10.4-1           OK
libopenmpifh12           1.10.7-1           OK
libopenmpifh40           3.1.3-1            OK
libopenmpiusef08_40      3.1.3-1            OK
libopenmpiusetkr40       3.1.3-1            OK
libp11-kit0              0.23.15-1          OK
libpcre1                 8.43-1             OK
libpipeline1             1.5.1-1            OK
libpkgconf3              1.6.0-1            OK
libpopt-common           1.16-2             OK
libpopt0                 1.16-2             OK
libquadmath0             7.4.0-1            OK
libreadline7             7.0.3-3            OK
libsigsegv2              2.10-2             OK
libsmartcols1            2.33.1-1           OK
libssl1.1                1.1.1d-1           OK
libstdc++6               7.4.0-1            OK
libtasn1_6               4.14-1             OK
libunistring2            0.9.10-1           OK
libuuid1                 2.33.1-1           OK
login                    1.13-1             OK
make                     4.2.1-2            OK
man-db                   2.7.6.1-1          OK
mintty                   3.0.6-1            OK
ncurses                  6.1-1.20190727     OK
openmpi                  3.1.3-1            OK
openmpi-debuginfo        3.1.1-2            OK
openssl                  1.1.1d-1           OK
p11-kit                  0.23.15-1          OK
p11-kit-trust            0.23.15-1          OK
pkg-config               1.6.0-1            OK
pkgconf                  1.6.0-1            OK
rebase                   4.4.4-1            OK
run                      1.3.4-2            OK
sed                      4.4-1              OK
tar                      1.29-1             OK
terminfo                 6.1-1.20190727     OK
terminfo-extra           6.1-1.20190727     OK
tzcode                   2019c-1            OK
tzdata                   2019c-1            OK
util-linux               2.33.1-1           OK
vim-minimal              8.1.1772-1         OK
w32api-headers           5.0.4-1            OK
w32api-runtime           5.0.4-1            OK
which                    2.20-2             OK
windows-default-manifest 6.4-1              OK
xz                       5.2.4-1            OK
zlib0                    1.2.11-1           OK
```

In **windows**(7), the program is compiled in a similar way but using a `cygwin` terminal

```
mpif90 -o elast_3d_mpi.exe elast3d_mpi.f
```

1 - when I try to run it using `mpirun` in the `cygwin` terminal, I have the follow error

```
$ mpirun -n 2 elast3d_mpi.exe
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry!  You were supposed to get help about:
    agent-not-found
from the file:
    help-plm-rsh.txt
But I couldn't find that topic in the file.  Sorry!
-----------------------------------------------------------------
[gauss:00824] [[INVALID],INVALID] FORCE-TERMINATE AT Not found:-13 - error /cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.3-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-3.1.3/orte/mca/plm/rsh/plm_rsh_component.c(327)
[gauss:00824] *** Process received signal ***
[gauss:00824] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[gauss:00824] Signal code: Address not mapped (23)
[gauss:00824] Failing at address: 0x0
Unable to print stack trace!
[gauss:00824] *** End of error message ***
```

2 - When I run it using the `orterun` implementation of `cygwing` in a `cmd` terminal, I have this error

```
C:\Users\io\Documents\elast-mpi>orterun.exe -np 2 elast3d_mpi
------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry!  You were supposed to get help about:
agent-not-found
from the file:
help-plm-rsh.txt
But I couldn't find that topic in the file.  Sorry!
------------------------------------------------------------------
[gauss:00827] [[INVALID],INVALID] FORCE-TERMINATE AT Not found:-13 - 
error /cygd
rive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.3-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-3.1.3/orte/
mca/plm/rsh/plm_rsh_component.c(327)
[gauss:00827] *** Process received signal ***
[gauss:00827] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[gauss:00827] Signal code: Address not mapped (23)
[gauss:00827] Failing at address: 0x0
Unable to print stack trace!
[gauss:00827] *** End of error message ***
1 [main] orterun 827 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: 
Dumping stack t
race to orterun.exe.stackdump
```

3 - Running the program in windows without `ortermpi.exe` the program outputs the next error

```
C:\Users\io\Documents\elast-mpi>elast3d_mpi
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry!  You were supposed to get help about:
agent-not-found
from the file:
help-plm-rsh.txt
But I couldn't find that topic in the file.  Sorry!
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[gauss:00833] [[INVALID],INVALID] FORCE-TERMINATE AT Not found:-13 - error /cygd
rive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.3-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-3.1.3/orte/
mca/plm/rsh/plm_rsh_component.c(327)
[gauss:00833] Process received signal 
[gauss:00833] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[gauss:00833] Signal code: Address not mapped (23)
[gauss:00833] Failing at address: 0x0
Unable to print stack trace!
[gauss:00833] End of error message 
[gauss:00832] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unable to start a daemon on th
e local node in file /cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.3-1.x86_
64/src/openmpi-3.1.3/orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at line 532
[gauss:00832] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Unable to start a daemon on th
e local node in file /cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.3-1.x86_
64/src/openmpi-3.1.3/orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at line 166
--------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):
orte_ess_init failed
--> Returned value Unable to start a daemon on the local node (-127) instead o
f ORTE_SUCCESS
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):
ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
Returned "Unable to start a daemon on the local node" (-127) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred in MPI_Init
on a NULL communicator
MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort, and potentially your MPI job)
[gauss:00832] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but
am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
```

**Observations and questions**

- If the program is running without `mpirun` in **linux**, then it works without errors and without paralleling processing.
- Running the program in windows without `ortermpi.exe` the program outputs errors.
- It sounds like a running (environmental) problem.
- Is it the best way to compile this program in windows?
- Can I compile the same mpi fortran code program in both windows and linux?
- What can I try to compiling the program in order to do the program running in windows system?

Comment: *Is it the best way to compile this program in windows?*. No, a far better option would be to ditch Cygwin altogether, it's an unnecessary additional layer of complexity, and get yourself a copy of the Intel Fortran compiler for Windows, together with the Intel MPI libraries.  But that costs money.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , Can the Intel MPI libraries compile the **same code** compiled in linux? in other words, do I have to modify it to compiled with the intel MPI libraries?

Comment: It's not the Intel MPI libraries which compile anything, I meant to point you at the Intel Fortran compiler for that.  But yes, unless your code uses vendor-specific or platform-specific extensions to the language or to the MPI standard, the same sources will build on either platform, and run.

Comment: yes, in fact my last question is more related with the differences between the openmpi (linux working compilation) and MPI implementations.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : Just for clarification: Intel Parallel Studio (which includes Fortran/MPI for all platforms) is free of charge for students, educators, and open source developers. (I have no affiliation with Intel)

Comment: @King - even better then !  And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: i just get shocked that we have same problem in a same time! currently im trying to run mpi via cygwin with same error! dont you found any solution yet?

Comment: try to install package openssh? i just fixed my problem right now

Comment: @payam_sbr yes the installation of the **openssh** package allows to run it  in windows for the cases 1) and 2).

Comment: Is there a way to compile all my code need in order to run in windows without the manual installation of the cygwin package in each machine where the code will to run?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @payam_sbr the installation of the `openssh` package allows to run the program in parallel in **windows**.

**Test**

After installation of the `openssh` package the program can be run in windows:

1 - Using the **cygwin** terminal

```
mpirun -n 2 ./elast3d_mpi.exe
```

2 - Or by using the **cmd** terminal

```
orterun -np 2 ./elast3d_mpi.exe
```

In both cases the result is the same like in **linux**

```
There are 2  processors running this job.
 Rank# 0 d1 = 1   d2 = 64
 Rank# 1 d1 = 65  d2 = 128
 ...
```

**Observation**

The installation of the openssh solved the problem for the cases 1) and 2), so the problem (run the code in parallel in windows with cygwin) is solved.

In the other hand, the installation of all cygwing packages to run the program in other machines is not very practical in terms of the distribution of the program.

Is there a way to compile all my code need in order to run in windows without the manual installation of the cygwin package in each machine where the code will to run? What are the options?